# Disagreeing with premise of question - answer or comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, accepted-answer

Sometimes, the correct response to a question is strongly disagreeing with the premise of the question.

If the premise is noted as an assumption or unsubstantiated, then an answer can obviously just disprove that premise.

If the premise is not explicit, but implicit in the question is an understanding or belief which the answerer believes to be incorrect (and therefore not a question), should disproving the premise be an answer or a comment? Technically, it isn't an answer, it is simply destroying the question?